# Referencing deleted entities in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have the following setup: there various entities (`Projects`, `Tests`, `Users`) and then there are `TestReports`. The `TestReports` reference the other entities and also some extra data in filesystem.

The reports are generated and are never deleted (for the auditing purposed). However, the other entities can be deleted. This leads to situation, when report references some deleted entity. This is OK from business point of view, the report could just display `[deleted id123]` instead of deleted entity label and it would be fine. However, I am getting `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException`, when I try to load a report which references deleted entity.

Is there a way to tell Hibernate/JPA to just create phantom object with ID and some `isDeleted` flag in such a case?

In Hibernate Envers documentation, I have found they support something like that when traversing the revision history, but I haven't find a way to use it in 'normal' entities.

**From the Envers documentation:**

> The second parameter, selectDeletedEntities, specifies if revisions, in which the entity was deleted should be included in the results. If yes, such entities will have the revision type DEL and all fields, except the id, null.

I am aware of workaround by introducing `deleted` flag on all objects and use if for *soft* deletion, instead of actual removal. But this adds an extra overhead, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking. You can tell hibernate to set a null on the field rather than trowing an EntityNotFoundException, by using the `@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` annotation. There isn't much documentation about it, you can find how to use it [here](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html#d0e2064).

Comment: Thanks, this seems like almost what I wanted. Do you know if there is a standard way how to distinguish between actual no reference and ignored not-found?

Comment: I don't know and I don't think hibernate provides such facility :S.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar situation and I'd done this:
I never delete these things. Rather, I set a `deletion time` for those which are deleted. When loading data, the objects are fetched successfully, but as I check their `deletion time` I show `[deleted]`.

However it is the solution I came up with, you might find another one.
**UPDATED**
You can try this one as well:
Catch `javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException` and manually insert any value you like to that field. In this case you are able to see which are deleted and which are actually having no reference.

Comment: Thanks, your solution definitely provides more flexibility, but would be probably overkill for me.

Comment: I might miss something, but I don't understand, how I can help myself by catching `EntityNotFoundException` when calling `query.getResultList() '.

Comment: When an exception rises, it means that that entity does not exist, right? So you can manually have an instance of that entity with your desired values.

Comment: `query.getResultList()` returns list of `TestRuns`, when it throws an `EntityNotFoundException`, then it basically means, that one of these `TestRun`s references deleted object.